# how to align text box and text in same line in a form for all orientations

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile, android-orientation

i am developing a jquery web page in which i have user name and pwd field. i want to align username and its input text box to its right. but when i put it in the android phone the alignment changes in landscape orientation. i need to align this text box and text in the middle of the page where it does not changes even though orientation changes. please help me in this regard. my code is.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
<div id="a" class="uname">
<label for="name"><font size="1" color="black">  User Name:  </font></label>
<input type="text" name="name"  id="text" data-mini="true" value=""/>
</div>
<div id="b" class="uname">
<label for="password"><font size="1" color="black">Password : </font></label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="text" data-mini="true" value=""/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, hope this works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/8cHKB/

Change your inline CSS to match your requirement.

Sometimes, you can also use `data-inline="true"` instead of `display: inline-block`. Consider your browser and device capability as well.

Comment: hi, my main problem is i am unable to display the uname and pwd form elements in middle of the page. and also in the solution which you have provided works as text box is below the text. but im my case it has to be near the text like. Uname -----------------

Comment: thank you i got it. but can you please help me to align exactly in the middle of the page which looks centered in any orientations. and also help me in aliging this user name and password elements one below the other. like User name[____________]      <br>without using br tag                Password[__________]

Comment: @krishnamoorthy You can play around with the width (using percentages) or you can use media queries in terms of orientation if you want the boxes to be displayed depending on the device orientation. It is easier to test this with an actual device.