# how do i align text and text box one below the other. help me and also i have to align in the excat center of the page and not on the top-center

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

do anybody know how to align a div in the middle of tht page and not in the top-center . which must have a white background.please help me in this regard. help me to attain this without

my div is

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
```

User Name:

```
<div id="b" style="display: inline-block">
<label for="password"><font size="1" color="black">Password : </font></label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="pwd" data-mini="true" value="" style="width: 45%;float: right"/></div>
```

Comment: so data-role is the only element in your page?

Comment: If some you guys are wondering what he is talking about, [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14619296/how-to-align-text-box-and-text-in-same-line-in-a-form-for-all-orientations/14620391#comment20425150_14620391)  .

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if this is exactly what your looking for, but this is how you can center an element in the page, assuming there is nothing else there.

```
<div id='b'>
some element
</div>

<style>
#b{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
margin: auto;
width: 100px;
height: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that`YourDivClass`  is a div which is located in center .

```
.YourDivClass
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;

    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;

    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of jQuery Mobile unique functionality pure CSS can not be used for perfect content centering.

Here's a working example created specifically for jQM: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/detPg/

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){   
    $("div[data-role='fieldcontain']").css('margin-top',getRealContentHeight()/2 - $('#b').height()/2);
    $('#b').css('margin-left',$("div[data-role='content']").outerWidth()/2 - $('#b').width()/2);
});

function getRealContentHeight() {
    var header = $("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    } 
    return content_height;
}
```

Usually horizontal centering can be achieved only with css, but because of new jQM 1.3 changes even it must be calculated through the javascript.